# undefined method for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm receiving an **undefined method `site_name' for nil:NilClass** error for the following. Would appreciate any help. I'm trying to list the site_name in the Site table and i'm not sure how best to resolve the issue.

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :site_id, :site_name, :region

      has_many :trials, :foreign_key => "site_id"

    end

    class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :trial_id, :site_id, :year, :trial_type

      scope :year, ->(year) { where(year: year) }
      scope :trial_id, ->(trial_id) { where(trial_id: trial_id) }

      belongs_to :site

    end
```

My Controller:

```
class TrialsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @years = Trial.group('year').order('year DESC')
    end

  def trial
    @trial = Trial.trial_id(params[:trial_id])
  end

**def list
@list = Trial.year(params[:year]).order(:region_id).joins(:sites).where('sites.site_id' => :site_id)
```

end**

```
end
```

My view:

```
    <% @list.each do |list| %>
        <tr>
        <td>
      <%= link_to list.site.site_name, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) %>
        </td>
        <td>    
        <%= link_to list.trial_type, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) unless list.trial_type.blank? %>
        </td>
        <td>    
        <%= link_to list.trial_type, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) %>
        </td>
        <td>    
        <%= link_to list.planted_at, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) unless list.planted_at.blank? %>
        </td>
        <td>    
        <%= link_to list.picked_at, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) unless list.picked_at.blank? %>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Maybe just one of your list entries doesn't have site?

Comment: I'm trying to access site_name from the site database.

Answer (score 1):

What if you just change the line to this:

`<%= link_to list.site.site_name, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) if list.site.try(:site_name) %>`

Also, you could do a `Site.where(site_name: nil)` in the Rails console to see which site doesn't have a name.

Comment: No luck with the above. Thanks for replying Benjamin.

Comment: Made a tiny mistake with the conditional. Please try again.

Comment: Don't get the error any more, but it doesn't list anything either, blank. Would I have to call Site in my controller along with the '@list = Trial.year(params[:year]).order(:region_id)' variable?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want page crush even if there is not site for list, you could try to use this

```
list.site.try(:site_name)
```

but I think that you should use another flow, like

1. Do not let to create list without site.
2. Do not list lists without sites.

Comment: Still no luck with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide about your default site name, eg. `"Example.com"`. And then you simply define it on nil:

```
def nil.site_name
  "Example.com"
end
```

And the error will go away.

Comment: This method works but, how can I best select the corresponding site_name where sites.site_name = trials_site_id? I seem to be having troubles joining the two tables together.

Comment: I'm not a Rails expert, and the solution that I offered is merely a hack, a quick kluge. Finding the truly good solution to your question is beyond my capacities.